# Why does using sort, skip and limit together return nothing when used with the intent of pagination?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, debugging, pagination

I'd like to paginate the DB data and sorting it by using the `lastAccessed` property by using a few built-in functions but for some reason, it doesn't work for me.

I've been searching on the web a way around this but to no avail.  Any feedback would appreciated

The below returns correct data as intended

```
let query = { 
   playerId : playerId, 
};

let cursor = await collection.find(query).toArray();

context.res = {
   body: cursor
}
```

the data:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "123"
    },
    "playerId": "373",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1657740790888
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "456"
    },
    "playerId": "873",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1521840147670
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "789"
    },
    "playerId": "273",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1521936685099
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "876"
    },
    "playerId": "982",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1521585248062
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "663"
    },
    "playerId": "023",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1521584952840
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "234"
    },
    "playerId": "998",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1521692015368
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "232"
    },
    "playerId": "322",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1521585085851
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "342"
    },
    "playerId": "131",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1652882094707
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "298"
    },
    "playerId": "233",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1522843298281
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "id": "221"
    },
    "playerId": "3452",
    "image": "someUrl.com",
    "lastAccessed": 1522843506264
  }
]
```

However, whenever I do:

```
let query = { 
   playerId : playerId, 
};

let cursor = await collection.find(query);
cursor.limit(10);
cursor.skip(10);
cursor.sort({"lastAccessed" : -1});

context.res = {
   body: cursor
}
```

It returns nothing.  This where I'm stuck.

Comment: Isn't the order you want `sort`, `skip`, `limit`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs whichever order works, I just want to use them together.

Comment: Well, does `let cursor = await collection.find(query).sort({"lastAccessed" : -1}).skip(10).limit(10);` work?

Comment: @rickhg12hs it doesn't work.  I get an error that says `"Cannot read property 'skip' of undefined"`.

Comment: You are returning the `.toArray()` results in the first example but the cursor directly in the second one?

Comment: @user20042973 yes.  you need to use `.toArray()` when solely using `.find()`.

Answer (score 0):

> you need to use .toArray() when solely using .find()

The qualifier of "*when solely using .find()*" isn't correct here. All of the following commands return a cursor object:

- `.find()`
- `.limit()`
- `.skip()`
- `.sort()`

That is why you can do something like chain `.find().limit().sort()` together the same way that you can do so with just `.find().sort()`. The cursor object itself is just a way to access the associated data, but it is the actual act of iterating the cursor which retrieves the data. Forcing the results into an array (via `.toArray()`) is one way to force that iteration.

More information about cursors specific to the Node.js driver is [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/cursor/).

You are currently just returning the *cursor* instead of the results with your second approach. You can try changing the latter code to something like this:

```
let cursor = await collection.find(query)
  .limit(10);
  .skip(10);
  .sort({"lastAccessed" : -1})
  .toArray();
```

The above will return the *results* to the client in the same manner that your initial test (of just `find(query).toArray()` was doing).

Also from the comments, [this question was raised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74448422/why-does-using-sort-skip-and-limit-together-return-nothing-when-used-with-the-i#comment131424473_74448422):

> Isn't the order you want `sort`, `skip`, `limit`?

Generally the answer is "yes". This makes a big difference when it comes to expressing the same type of operation via an aggregation pipeline. I would recommend such a change to add some clarity.

However, when it comes to `find()` operations the ordering is well-defined. The implementation will do things in "the correct order" regardless of how they are chained/expressed by the client. I've left the original ordering in this answer to demonstrate both this and the fact that the main problem is related to a cursor (instead of results) being returned to the client.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, greatly appreciated!  I've already tried your suggestion before I even saw you've responded but unfortunately, it gave me an error that says `Error=2, Details='Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest (400);`.  I guess we're kind of going in the right track now?  I'm really not sure how else to go about this!

Comment: That response is a generic wrapper around some other error message. We would really need to know what error (if any) the server is encountering. Does your initial code return the same message? This is arguably a different issue which deserves its own question as it could be more related to the structure of the web server code than the MongoDB query itself